# Multer doesn't upload my Image to my Backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, multer

I try to implement multer to upload files for my galery.
Unfortunately it doesn't work.
Network shows me this error:

```
msg: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename')"
```

I guess the error is somewhere here:

```
upload.single('galery')
```

Bcs i try to console.log my file insite the storage function and it seems like it's not used at all. I couldn't even print a "Hello World" in there atm.
That's why I'm getting an error after:

const image = req.file.filename;

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const galeryCtrl = require('../controllers/galeryCtrl');
const multer = require('multer');
const shortid = require('shortid');
const path = require('path');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '../images');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    console.log(file);
    cb(
      null,
      shortid.generate() + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)
    );
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  const allowedFileTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png'];
  if (allowedFileTypes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

let upload = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter });

router
  .route('/galery')
  .get(galeryCtrl.getGaleries)
  .post(upload.single('galery'), async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const image = req.file.filename;
      const galeryCheck = await Galery.findOne({ image });
      // Check if already exist
      if (galeryCheck)
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'already exists' });
      const newGalery = new Galery({ image, name: shortid.generate() });
      await newGalery.save();
      res.json({ msg: 'success' });
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message });
    }
  });
```

```
 const onFileChange = (e) => {
    setGalery(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('galery', galery);
    console.log(formData);
    axios({
      url: '/api/galery',
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
      data: formData,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return response;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <input type='file' onChange={onFileChange} />
            <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

I tried to change the code but this brings new errors.
First i was need to remove the value={galery} from my input, otherwise I am getting a white screen.

But now I've new errors:

POST http://localhost:3000/api/galery 500 (Internal Server Error)

Error: Request failed with status code 500 (from the console.log(error)

Answer (score 1):

Backend code looks good to me but while sending the file in the request can you try like below.

```
onFileChange(e) {
    setGalery(e.target.files[0])
}

onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('galery', galery)
    axios.post("serverurlhere", formData, {
    }).then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })
}

// OR ANOTHER WAY
onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('galery', galery)
  axios({
        url:"serverurlhere",
        method:'post',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        data: formData,
  })
  .then(response => { 
        return response;
  })
  .catch(error =>{
        console.log(error);
  });
}

<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
  <input type="file" onChange={this.onFileChange} />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please watch my edited post. I've new errors with this change

Comment: I am not seeing any object created with formData. Please try axios.post as I mentioned. Remove image attribute and use formData as I mentioned

Comment: you need to append galery to the formData object. I am not seeing that snippet in u r post. Please check the snippet I used.

Comment: I edit my current code and errors

Comment: I have added one more way of making api call using axios. Can you please try that way once? Can you also please check whether any data is being sent in the request or not in the network calls of the browser?

Comment: Less errors but still some + Network says still: msg : "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename')"

Comment: In the request payload is file data has been sent or not?

Comment: Also can you do console.log(galery) and check whether file data is there or not?